# Copy GC Storage through multiple accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cp, gsutil

Is there a way to use`qsutil -m cp....` with multiple accounts? 
I am trying to copy whole bucket/storage from one GCP account to another GCP account. 
With `gcloud auth` I add multiple accounts but don't know how to set accounts in cp command. 
Someting like `gsutil -m cp gs//bucketname gs//bucketname` but between two different GCP.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant access to both buckets to the service/user account you authenticated with in gsutil/gcloud.

In your [Developer Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser), click on the 3-vertical-dots icon next to the bucket and add the necessary permissions to your account. Source bucket should give it read access and destination bucket should give it write access.

Once done, you should be able to run the following command successfully:

```
gsutil -m cp gs://source_bucket_name gs://destination_bucket_name
```

Comment: Thanks this works great, one thing - should be: gs://[bucket]